# Copy array element modify and add again

Tags: javascript, typescript

Original array is `newData`. I wanted add one more array element to newData and added array Element should have `Rank 1`.

Issue is Rank is getting updated to 1 for both the records. Rank should be 1 for second record and 1st record should be `null`

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here.

```
let newData = [{
    "key1": {
        "cc":'IND'   
    },          
    "key2": {
        "rank": null
    }
}];

let setData = newData.concat(newData.slice());

setData.forEach(data => { 
    data.key2.rank =+ 1;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```js
let newData = [{"key1": {"cc":'IND' }, "key2": {"rank": null}}];

    // Concatenate arrays use spread operator and can use map rather than slice
    let setData = [...newData, ...newData.map(data => { 
        /* Objects are passed by reference, you need to break the reference
         * to create the clone of the object. */
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        data.key2.rank =+ 1; 
        return data;
    })];

console.log(setData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setData.forEach(data => { 
  data.key2.rank += 1;
});
```

Try to flip your operator from `=+` to `+=` instead

Comment: if i use += 1, rank is changing to 2 for both the records

Comment: @ArunK: If you don't mind can you construct the result that you're expecting and include in your question?